# Is it a bad idea to fit a time-series in pieces?

Tags: time-series, arima

I am just starting to learn time-series analysis and I was got great results with an ARIMA(3,0,2) model when I tested against the last 5000 hours. I know this doesnt apply to all of the data when you consider it since the 1980's, but

1. Am I justified in restricting the range to only current (within the last 10 years or so) of data because the market has changed so much?
2. Can I use the fact that an ARIMA(3,0,2) model works in the most recent 5000 hours to improve an overall model?

Comment: I don't think the question title and title contents are well matched. If the question is "Is it a good idea just to use those data I think are relevant to my problem?" my answer is yes, naturally,  and indeed anything else sounds a bad idea, although there can always be discussion about precisely where to draw the line. If the question is can I fit one model to this piece and another model, my answer is that you will have to work harder to convince most statistical people that that makes sense.

Comment: My question is exactly: can I fit one model to this piece and another model to another piece? I thought the title stated that accurately but I may be wrong. Would that be a more descriptive title?

Comment: You can. My general line is that you should not do this without really believing that the world in question changed completely and unequivocally at the break point. You're entering a minefield of justification and defence: why 2 models and not 3 or 13? Why those breakpoints etc.?

Comment: Depends on what is driving the process you are investigating. If there's a reason to assume some kind of change in the process at a given point in time, then you could restrict your model. Otherwise you're only going to remove information from your model and potentially reduce its performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 - Yes. Restricting the data range is one way to accommodate that shift in the market.
 #2 - First question would be whether you even NEED an overall model. For forecasting purposes, you wouldn't. The next issue would be how you are going to accommodate those market changes (maybe with a regressor added to the ARIMA model?). Hyndman's free online textbook has a chapter on this. Finally, if you go through some automated ARIMA identification scheme with the regression, you might also force the (3,0,2) model to see if it does just about as well; given a choice of equivalently fitting models, choosing the one that does best on recent data is a good choice.